# use x-init and a setter to update x-data variable and reflect it in the frontend

Tags: html, alpine.js

I am trying to call a function on init to change a x-data variable and reflect it in the frontend.
In the console the value is false but in the frontend the x-text and the x-if still react as if is true.
How do i get the frontend to reflect the change?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/alpinejs" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div x-data="{ val: true }" x-init="setVal()">
      <div><span x-text="val"></span></div>
      <template x-if="val">
        <div>Renders on x-if directive.</div>
      </template>
    </div>

    <script>
      function setVal() {
        this.val = false;
        console.log("val", this.val);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mutate a state directly inside `x-init` directive, or put `setVal()` function inside the Alpine.js context, so it can access and mutate the data.

```html
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<div x-data="{ val: true }" x-init="val = false">
  <div><span x-text="`Value of val: ${val}`"></span></div>
</div>

<div x-data="{ val: true, setVal() {this.val = false} }" x-init="setVal()">
  <div><span x-text="`Value of val: ${val}`"></span></div>
</div>
```